# Excel Math Formula

Tags: excel-formula

Is there a way in a simple excel expression to store the data of a formula that is collecting data to use it else where in the same expression? Maybe that doesn't make much sense, so I'll try and detail it here:

```
J6=1 J7=2 J8=3 J9=4
=(J6*8)+(J7*4)+(J8*2)+(J9*1) this equals 26
```

.

I then need to receive 10% of this. Obviously (1-10%) will get me to 23.4, but I need it to show the actual difference. In this case, 2.6.

Comment: just for fun: `=ROUND(0.1*SUMPRODUCT(J6:J9,2^(4-ROW(1:4))),0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just guessing... something like this?

```
=0.1*((J6*8)+(J7*4)+(J8*2)+(J9*1))
```

Will give you 2.6 in your example (0.1 = 10%).

Comment: Yea, that works. Awesome! Is there a way to round it down to the whole number even if its 2.99999? Without formatting the cell?

Comment: try round it with =ROUND(0.1*((J6*8)+(J7*4)+(J8*2)+(J9*1)),0), the second argument "0" to the round function makes it round it to the next integer

Comment: Nice, appreciate it!

Comment: The FLOOR or ROUNDDOWN or INT or TRUNCATE are a few functions that will *'round it **down** to the whole number'*.